# Allowing multiple types to be convert to text per timestep

Tags: c++, design-patterns, text, rendering

I am working on my GUI system and I am need of help for a design pattern.

For one of my GUI elements, it can have text that needs to be updated each timestep. However, there are several different types of variables (for the text) that can be updated every frame, such as float, int, unsigned int, bool and strings. While I understand the need to use some things such as `atoi` to convert int's to char*'s, my problem arises when thinking of an "elegant" solution. What I have thought of doing what having multiple enums such as `TEXT_IS_FLOAT`, `TEXT_IS_INT`, etc, then having functions such as `SetTextAsFloat(float value)`, while having the object on some sort of update loop so it can do conversions such as aoti every timestep. My fear to doing it that way is the code will eventually look very cumbersome with supporting a lot of different value types, along with no using a "good code design".

Does anyone know of any suggestions on how I could design such a system to update text on an object that can have multiple types of type input for the text? How would the class store the potential typed variable (preferably without a template).

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you have the STL ostringstream, which acts like a stream, but constructing a string instead of writing to a file. Here is an example:

```
#include <sstream>  // istringstream, ostringstream, stringstream
#include <string>   // for string objects

using namespace std;  // personally I don't like std::everything...

// returns a string represented what was just updated
string build_value()
{
    int my_int;
    bool my_bool;
    float my_float;
    // the above vars are updated somehow...

    ostringstream s;  // build a string using stream syntax

    // and now the logic

   if (updated_int) {
       s << my_int;
       return s.str();  // this is a string object
   }
   else if (updated_bool) {
       s << my_bool;
       return s.str();
   }
   else if (updated_float) {
       s << my_float;
       return s.str();
   }
}
```

You could also create a helper template function:

```
template <typename T>
string type_to_string(T t)
{
    ostringstream s;
    s << t;
    return s.str();
}
```

which works on all types that the stream is defined on.

Comment: small typo: should be "template <typename T>"

Comment: What would an example of how to store the typed variable in a class look like? (Without templating the class).

Comment: @Vaughn Cato: Can you take a look at my comment?

Comment: @chadb:  Are you using boost?  They have a variant class that allows any type of data to be stored in  a single variable.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato: I am not using boost.

Comment: @chadb: Do you have a single text field instance that will show various types of values, or do you mean that different instances will show different types of values?

Comment: I have a single text field instance that will show various types of values.